# Add a new aspx page to a published website

Tags: c#, asp.net, publishing-site

I have a .Net website which is published. Now I need to add a new page to the website but I do not have the source code which means that I cannot recompile and republish the website. I know that I can add an HTML page for this as the content for the new page is just plain HTML but that would show .html extension in the browser which I don't want. Is there any way to add an aspx page or html page is the only option I have ?

Comment: Yes you can add new pages without recompiling. I think you just need to not reference a code behind file.

Comment: Thanks your advice worked for me. Post is as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add pages without recompiling, just ensure the pages don't reference a code-behind file. You'll still be able to use code in the actual page itself, as well as reference controls (`.ascx` files).

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you can add a create an application and then add it as an application under the original website. As in, in IIS, right click on the original site, then Add Application; and put your new application into it.  Your new application will have it's own application pools and is an application by its own right without needing the original site's data.